# Using deferred.defer within a transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-app-engine-python

The Google app engine [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#enqueuing_tasks_in_cloud_datastore_transactions) state:

> You can enqueue a task as part of a Google Cloud Datastore
>   transaction, such that the task is only enqueued—and guaranteed to be
>   enqueued—if the transaction is committed successfully.

and gives this example:

```
@ndb.transactional
def do_something_in_transaction():
    taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker', transactional=True)
```

But it isn't clear to me if the same holds true for tasks created with the `deferred` library. For this:

```
@ndb.transactional
def do_something_in_transaction():
    deferred.defer(my_function)
```

is the task only enqueued if the transaction is successfully committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally `deferred.defer` is just a wrapper around `taskqueue.add`. From the SDK's
`google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py` file:

```
def defer(obj, *args, **kwargs):
  ...
  transactional = kwargs.pop("_transactional", False)
  ...
  try:
    task = taskqueue.Task(payload=pickled, **taskargs)
    return task.add(queue, transactional=transactional)
```

So you just need to do the equivalent, if you want the deferred task enqueued transactionally:

```
@ndb.transactional
def do_something_in_transaction():
    deferred.defer(my_function, _transactional=True)
```